# Sequelize many to many relationship same table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

Hello you guys I have a question. Let's imagine we have social media.

## [image]

Let's imagine the users table looks like so. and just like in any other social media, users can comment other users pics. so we need a comments table that has a references to the user that posted the pic and the user that comments the pic.
[image]

So I need to findout a way to make a `belongsToMany` in `sequelize`.

[image]

So far I have an accounts.ts file

```js
import { AccountAttributes, Repository } from "@eneto/models";
import { DataTypes, Sequelize } from "sequelize";

/**
 * Account factory
 *
 * @param {import("sequelize").Sequelize} sequelize Sequelize database instance.
 * @returns {Repository<AccountAttributes>} Instance of Accounts Entity.
 */
function AccountFactory (sequelize: Sequelize): Repository<AccountAttributes> {
    return sequelize.define("accounts", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
        },
        psswrd: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        },
    }) as Repository<AccountAttributes>;
}

export { AccountFactory };
```

and on my index.ts I have it like:

```js
import { DB } from "@eneto/models";
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import { env } from "../utils/env-vars";
import { AccountInfoFactory } from "./account-info";
import { AccountFactory } from "./accounts";

const sequelize = new Sequelize(env["ENETO_DB_NAME"], env["ENETO_DB_USER"], env["ENETO_DB_PASSWORD"], {
    port: env["ENETO_DB_PORT"],
    host: env["ENETO_DB_HOST"],
    dialect: "postgres",
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000,
    },
});

const Accounts = AccountFactory(sequelize);
const AccountTypes = AccountTypesFactory(sequelize);
const AccountAddress = AddressFactory(sequelize);
const SocialMedia = SocialMediaFactory(sequelize);
const Educations = EducationFactory(sequelize);

AccountTypes.hasMany(Accounts);
AccountAddress.hasMany(Accounts);
Accounts.hasMany(SocialMedia);
Accounts.hasMany(Educations);
Accounts.hasMany(Experiences);
Accounts.hasMany(AccountInfo);
Accounts.hasMany(Media);

// I still dont know how to make a
Accounts.belongsToMany(Accounts);

export const db: DB = {
    Accounts,
    sequelize,
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer:

```js
Accounts.belongsToMany(Accounts,{ through: Comments,as: "to", foreignKey: "id" });
Accounts.belongsToMany(Accounts, { through: Comments, as: "from", foreignKey: "id" });
```