# Sequelize: many-to-many relationship to self, through another table?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, graph-theory, entity-relationship

In `sequelize.js`, is it possible to relate a table to itself through another table?

I'm attempting to create a basic graph model.  I have two relevant tables: `Node` and `Edge`.  I wish to construct a many-to-many relation from `Node` to itself, through `Edge`.

**Example**: to have a `Node` named "Dave", an `Edge` with the `predicate` "Loves", and another `Node` named "Sarah".

In the `Node` table, `id` is the primary key.  In the `Edge` table, the fields `subject_node_id` and `direct_object_node_id` should point to Node `id`.

Here is a quick-and-dirty ERD of what I'm going for:

[image: entity relationship diagram of desired result]

Here is my best attempt so far.  The following code creates the table columns OK, but does not create the rows as expected.  The `create` method may be totally wrong; for example, there should be a way to set `predicate`, but I don't know where to put it:

```js
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

(async () => {
  try {
    const db = await new Sequelize({
      dialect: "sqlite",
      storage: "./db/db.db",
    });
    
    const Node = await db.define("node", {
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
    });
    
    const Edge = await db.define("edge", {
      subject_node_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      predicate: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      direct_object_node_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
    });

    await Node.sync({ force: true });
    await Edge.sync({ force: true });

    await Node.belongsToMany(Node, {
      through: "Edge",
      as: "subjects",
      foreignKey: "id",
      otherKey: "subject_node_id"
    });

    await Node.belongsToMany(Node, {
      through: "Edge",
      as: "direct_objects",
      foreignKey: "id",
      otherKey: "direct_object_node_id"
    });
    
    await Node.create(
      {
        name: "Dave",
        // Loves ??
        subjects: [{
          name: "Sarah"
        }]
      },
    );

    console.log("created");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

I did find [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965582/sequelize-many-to-many-relationship-same-table), but the accepted answer doesn't quite get there.  Any additional ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

(async () => {
  try {
    const db = await new Sequelize({
      dialect: "sqlite",
      storage: "./db/db.db",
    });

    const Node = db.define("node", {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
    });
    const Edge = db.define("edge", {
      subjectId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      predicate: DataTypes.STRING,
      dobjectId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    });

    await Node.belongsToMany(Node, {
      through: Edge,
      as: "subjects",
      foreignKey: "dobjectId",
    });

    await Node.belongsToMany(Node, {
      through: Edge,
      as: "dobjects",
      foreignKey: "subjectId",
    });

    await db.sync({force: true});

    const dave = await Node.create({ name: "Dave" });
    const sarah = await Node.create({ name: "Sarah" });

    await dave.addDobject(sarah, { through: {
      predicate: "Loves"
    }});
    await sarah.addDobject(dave, { through: {
      predicate: "Loves"
    }});

    const result = await Node.findOne({
      where: { name: "sarah" },
      include: ["subjects", "dobjects"],
    });
    console.log(result);

    console.log("created");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```